# NSWindow set frame higher than screen

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nswindow, nswindowcontroller

I need help. I have an app like Adium with vertical sliders. But my app change the window height, depending on content. In case if the Screen height less than my app'a window height my window reduces the height automatically.

When I'm trying to use setFrame to my window and set window.frame.size.height higher than screen height then nothing happens.

So the question is: how to set window frame higher than screen height?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default, the frameworks make sure you cannot resize your window to be outside the screen frame. To change this behavior, subclass your `NSWindow`, and override the `constrainFrameRect:toScreen:` method to return the unaltered frame; something like this:

```
- (NSRect)constrainFrameRect:(NSRect)frameRect toScreen:(NSScreen *)screen
{
  //return the unaltered frame, or do some other interesting things
  return frameRect;
}
```

Comment: Here is the swift version: `override func constrainFrameRect(_ frameRect: NSRect, to screen: NSScreen?) -> NSRect {
        return frameRect
    }`